# Odoo V10 - Groups and subgroups

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I created a main group and subgroups (which inherit from the main group). I would like to link a subgroup for each record of a table. Is it possible with Odoo? If so, can you enlighten me? Here is a diagram of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Thanks you !

EDIT: I want to do that because I do not want any user to have access to any information. More precisely, and compared to the diagram in my question.

```
Main group = Group Canteen
Sub Group 1 = Group Canteen City 1 -> User 1
Sub Group 2 = Town Canteen Group 2 -> User 2
Sub Group 3 = Group Canteen City 3 -> User 3
Then for the records. All records are part of the same model listing all canteen locations. So :
record 1 = canteen place 1
record 2 = canteen place 2
record 3 = canteen place 3
```

To summarize, I would like for example that the user 1 is only access to the information of the place canteen 1

Thanks You !

Comment: Vous pouvez ajouter un champ dans la table user, et un champ calculable dans votre model qui calcule la valeur de champ ajouté dans la table user pour utilisateur actuel

Comment: Et après vous pouvez cacher le champ selon le champ caluclable

Comment: You welcome !!!!

Comment: The true question is : why you want to do that ? Because according to this answer, may be there are some more simple things to do.

Comment: Guys the English language is required on this platform. Please translate the question and comments to English or they will be flagged by me or other SO users.

Comment: I will edit my question to add more information :)

Comment: Have you tried using a rule instead of groups? Rules are dynamic and may be able to adapt to many situations, whereas groups are static and need to be maintained corresponding to your records

Comment: No, I do not think so. How to proceed ? Is there documentation? cordially

Comment: See section "record rules"in the Odoo Security documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/security.html